# How to embed the youtube player and facebook api using bootsrap3?

Tags: html, css, facebook, youtube, embed

everyone.

My name is Cody, and I'm a student/amateur web designer who got hired to create a website for a family friend.

I'm using bootstrap3 to make the site responsive, but I am running into an issue trying to embed the youtube player API and the facebook page API together on the homepage of the site.

The col-8 is supposed to serve as the main content area, while the col-4 is meant to serve as a side-bar/sharing section.

The page renders the youtube player correctly, but doesn't display any content w/i the col-4 or thereafter.
However, if I disable the youtube player, the page will load correctly.

If you could help me figure out what's wrong, that'd be awesome.

```
<body>
<div class="container row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">.col-sm-8
        <h3>What is Roger's Lake of the Woods Adventures?</h3>
        <p>testing testing</p>
        <!-- Youtube Player API Placement -->
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"
        id="ytplayer" 
        type="text/html" 
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=0&origin=http://lakeofthewoodsadventures.com" 
        />
        </div>
        <!-- End of Youtube Player API Placement -->
    </div>
    <div class="darkBG col-sm-4">
    <!-- Facebook Page Feed API Placement -->
        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Rogers-Lake-of-the-Woods-Adventures/597978003639919" 
        data-width="280" 
        data-hide-cover="true" 
        data-show-facepile="false" 
        data-show-posts="true">
        <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Rogers-Lake-of-the-Woods-Adventures/597978003639919">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Rogers-Lake-of-the-Woods-Adventures/597978003639919">
        Roger&#039;s Lake of the Woods Adventures
        </a>
        </blockquote>
        </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End of Facebook Page Feed API Placement -->
    </div>
</div>
<script src="Local Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks!
- Cody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<iframe src="">youtube code**</iframe>**
```

You must open and closed the iframe tag.

Comment: Omg >. < ... Thank you both so much. I thought that the iframe was a stand-alone element.

Answer (score 2):

try adding a `</iframe>` tag.

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item"
        id="ytplayer" 
        type="text/html" 
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=0&origin=http://lakeofthewoodsadventures.com" 
        ></iframe>
```